# qTip change text of specific tooltip after for each

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, qtip2

I have an html page with some inputs and textareas.
I want them to have qTip with different texts.

Here is my attempt
First I add a qTip to every element,

```
$('input, textarea').each(function() {
        $(this).qtip(
                { 
                content : 'generated', //this is for debug
                position : {

                    my : 'center left',
                    at : 'center right',
                    adjust : {
                        x : 90
                    }
                }
            });
});
```

and then I'm trying to change an qTip text like this

`$("#firstName").qtip('option', 'content.text', 'adwd');`

but it is not working.

I tried this

```
$("#lastName").qtip({
    content : 'text text'
});
```

which is working fine but it overrides the position

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code working for me:

```
$("#firstName").qtip('option', 'content.text', 'new tooltip content')
```

If you have to change it on an event (eg over or similar) try using this code:

```
// make sure you target a specific tip
var qapi = $('#firstName').data('qtip'),
newtip = 'new tooltip content'
qapi.options.content.text = newtip; // update content stored in options
qapi.elements.content.text(newtip); // update visible tooltip content
qapi.redraw(); // redraw to adjust tooltip borders
```

The code update only a specific option and leave the others as are.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/L7fs5/